# Find DST (Daylight Savings Time) timestamp using Objective-C/C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, dst

Is there a way to get the specific date (way) when daylight davings begins and ends for each country using C or Objective-C?

In the Mexico, summer time begins on the first Sunday in April at 2:00am, and ends on the last Sunday in October at 2:00am. In many POSIX systems this is written as

```
M4.1.0/2,M10.5.0/2
(Begins: Month 4, 1st Sunday at 02:00AM, Ends: Month 10, last Sunday at 02:00AM)
```

I know it is possible to know if daylight savings is currently active using

```
NSTimeZone* systemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
BOOL dstIsOn = [systemTimeZone isDaylightSavingTime];
```

and that it is possible to get the time until the next `Daylight Savings` begins

```
NSTimeZone* systemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSTimeInterval delta = [systemTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset];
```

**BUT: How would I go about finding the specific day that the daylight savings begins/ends?**

Is there some killer table out there that I have not been able to find?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI, in the US our daylight savings time has expanded by about 3 weeks on each end now.

Comment: @CarlVeazey You are indeed correct. Changed country to Méjico though would have gladly changed it to Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan had they observed DST.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is - you can use `[NSTimeZone nextDaylightSavingTimeTransitionAfterDate:]` method. This returns an `NSDate`, which you can use with `daylightSavingTimeOffsetForDate` to establish what the offset is.

Normally you'd use this to find the next offset, but you can obviously run it more than once with different dates to get a series of upcoming daylight saving changes. There is also a convenience method `nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition` which will always return the next transition.

Comment: Keep in mind that DST rules change more frequently then Apple releases iOS updates. So dates from NSTimeZone methods may be outdated. In our project we use, as you called it, "killer table", which is updated manually.

Comment: @Jeepston Yeah, I was aware of that...I don't happen to be so lucky that your killer table is up for grabs? ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share it, I'm not the owner of the code.

Comment: This helped me perform the essentials of my problem. However, there was still a lot of NSString - hassling before I could get it in the format I wanted, eg. M4.1.0/2,M10.5.0/2.